# Why does running the Silverlight 5 Beta prompt me to install Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

When I run a Silverlight 5 project, the test page shows the 'Install Silverlight' logo. Clicking through shows the following detail:

Installed version: Silverlight 5 (5.0.60401.0)
Requested version: Silverlight 4 (4.0.60531.0)

What determines the requested version?

**Note**
The 'Target Silverlight Version' **is** set to version 5 in project properties.

I am running the Silverlight .xap in the MVC project host generated by Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Did you create the project initially in Silverlight 4 then change the target? The requested min version is in the hosting page settings on your Silverlight object. These HTML/ASPX pages are not changed when you change the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with the current RC version of Silverlight. The link in the template points to:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.60818.0

If you go to this page you will see that the requested version is hard-coded to the version you list above. Do you have the RC tools (60818) installed but only the Beta version (60401) of Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with SL5 RC. When they dropped the RC status a few months ago my Silverlight 5 apps finally quit trying to revert to SL4. They were doing this because at that time SL4 was the most recent 'full/stable' release of SL.